# Why did the Python3 command prompt change?

Tags: python-3.x

I have just started to learn Python3.  I downloaded the Anaconda package and tied in PyCharm.  From Pycharm I opened the Python console.  For a while I was getting the normal >>> command prompt.  For some unknown reason, it changed to In[2] format.  I must have done something.  How can I get back to the >>> command prompt?

Comment: Doesn't Anaconda ship with [IPython](http://ipython.org)? IPython displays the prompt in the way, you described. It seems, like PyCharm uses the IPython interpreter now, which then results into this prompt. Either change the interpreter in PyCharm or look, how to change it in IPython (just to have a more specific term to search for) :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I will try to determine exactly what PyCharm uses.  The confusing part is that for the first day, PyCharm used >>> for the prompt.  Then it changed to the other style.  I keep thinking that I did something to cause the change.

Comment: Maybe the restart of PyCharm caused it to actually load the other interpreter and prompt?

Comment: My brief research indicates that PyCharm auto loads IPython 2.3.1 . So everything is fine.  The tutorial books I am using always use >>> as a prompt.  They are not using PyCharm or IPython.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: After all it does no difference to the use of it. But if you are really desperate to change it, take a look at the [IPython Docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/intro.html). :)

Comment: I found a checkbox in PyCharm preferences.  Issue is resolved.

Comment: good to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the `ps1`:

```
bad prompt> import sys
bad prompt> sys.ps1 = '>>> '
>>> print('it works')
it works
>>>
```

Comment: I tied what you suggested but it didn't work.  I still have the In[12] type of prompt.

Comment: In[2]: import sys
In[3]: sys.ps1 = '>>> '
In[4]